# Nullpointer onClickListener on toggleButton why?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have problems with Android 2.2 I'm checking in my old device my new app and i get a nullpointer on this tooglebutton, i don't known why, in other device using 4.0.4 works like a charm.

I tried to Implement onClickListener to my class, and no results. The button is defined in the correct Xml layout. I post logcat's output, code and Xml.

Thanks.

```
public class Settings extends Activity {

ToggleButton toggleFb;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    toggleFb = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleFb);
    addListenerOnButtonFb();

}

public void addListenerOnButtonFb() {

    toggleFb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            fb = "1";

            if (toggleFb.isChecked()) {
                noti = "1";

            } else {
                noti = "0";

            }

        }

    });

}
```

LogCat

```
01-22 23:23:29.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5493):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
01-22 23:23:29.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5493):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
01-22 23:23:29.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5493):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-22 23:23:29.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5493):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
01-22 23:23:29.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5493):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-22 23:23:29.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5493):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-22 23:23:29.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5493):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
01-22 23:23:29.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5493):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-22 23:23:29.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5493):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-22 23:23:29.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5493):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
01-22 23:23:29.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5493):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
01-22 23:23:29.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5493):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-22 23:23:29.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5493): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-22 23:23:29.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5493):     at my.package.Settings.addListenerOnButtonFb(Settings.java:97)
01-22 23:23:29.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5493):     at my.package.Settings.onCreate(Settings.java:43)
01-22 23:23:29.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5493):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-22 23:23:29.601: E/AndroidRuntime(5493):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
```

XML

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/toggleFb"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
    android:text="ToggleButton" />
```

Comment: Most obvious question is...are you sure there is such button with that ID in your view?

Comment: is 97 this line? toggleFb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { if so, try removing the method call from you oncreate and check if the button is really there on a 2.2 device

Comment: Yes, I posted the Xml of activity_settings.xml in layout, setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

Comment: Omg I'm idiot thanks both, the prob was I'm using layout-small and has different xmls :-) Big stupid fail. Tnaks both for your time and comments.